# Connecting iM881A-M to Arduino

Tags: arduino, pcb, uart, component-selection, lora

I want to connect iM881A-M LoRa module to arduino.
And I want to ask which external parts I need to connect it.

In datasheet there are many parts that I think I don't need to use.
Please help me , I am only student.
[image]

Comment: Consider moving your question to arduino stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the filter C1 over the power supply, but all the switches and LEDs seem to be for debug and indication. It would be recommended to have them especially during bring up. Once you are happy with its functionality you could possibly remove some of the LEDs / Switches.

[image]